# Is there a way to validate nodejs code before running it

Tags: node.js, linux, server

I am looking for a way to sign (locally) and validate (on the server) the code for a nodejs app that i am gonna be deploying.

I am thinking about creating a custom docker container that will check for a signature file (that contains hashes for all files in the project) and run the code only if it passes the check.

Is there something like that already exists?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you mean by "validating"? Are you trying to check for functionality? Security risks? Something else?

Comment: In this case i am worried about security, I want to prevent any non signed code from running.

Comment: This will require me to block any other ways of running code, such as
node -e "console.log('hello')"
or 
npx run-func file.js someFunction "just some parameter"

Comment: Does this help at all https://adrianhesketh.com/2022/01/26/verifying-download-hashes-during-docker-build/ ?  Yarn has hash checking on dependencies in yarn.lock.  You could also look into using git hooks on both the client side and server side https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks .  To block users from running code, you'll also want to look out for potential code injection attacks and run npm audit regularily to make sure your packages don't have vulnerabiliites